# Will google text search api omits the 'permanently closed' businesses?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I have been trying to get some 'permanently closed' businesses using [Google Text Search api](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search), but i couldn't.

[Here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ye+Olde+Curiosity+Shop/@47.6047367,-122.3392997,18z/data=!4m5!1m2!2m1!1s1001+Alaskan+Way+Pier+54+Seattle,+WA+98104+United+States%E2%80%8E!3m1!1s0x54906aae2d73cc87:0x63d4400775c57608?hl=en) is the business(**Ye Olde Curiosity Shop**) which is permanently closed(as per the Google Maps),

I used [Google AutoComplete api](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=Ye%20Olde%20Curiosity%20Shop%201001%20Alaskan%20Way%20Seattle,%20WA%2098104%20United%20States&key=Yourkey) to get the place_id(**Ye Olde Curiosity Shop**) and later used the same place_id against the  [Google Places Details api](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?key=Yourkey&reference=CmRVAAAA0YS-9j65mneSVEZIn6bmdOijqdeLENKmQwl0rLSGS2RAbQiEjTlsupCnnM5PBwer5YiEHqXH1BgknCU6__ZI7r_XGff0ifQ9B_F_BXy6M92uguHPrE10fhOHwX-8hLA1EhBbYYVmSSHsicYx0ProIHnjGhQ5qMpqrB7J8Et1vN-N9EqtPp8rBQ) and it says that the business is 'permanently closed'. (No issues)

But when i try to get the place_id for the business which has been closed(**Ye Olde Curiosity Shop**) using [Google Text Search api](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=Ye%20Olde%20Curiosity%20Shop,%201001%20Alaskan%20Way,%20Seattle,%20WA%2098104,%20United%20States&key=Yourkey) , then it is not giving me the exact matching business place_id.

My question is that the 'Google Text Search api' omits the closed businesses? because i don't have any problem in getting the place_id, when i used 'Google Auto Complete api'. I don't find any documentation saying this.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: What place_id do you get when you use the Google Text Search API?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Place ID [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#multiple-ids),

> Each place ID can refer to only one place, but a single place can have
>   more than one place ID.

The place_id you're getting when you use the AutoComplete and Places Details API was most likely added when that shop was still in business. So even if using the Text Search API gave you a different place_id, that should still be ok and you should be able to refer to that location and search for it using either ID. However, and this isn't explicitly stated in the documentation, I don't think the Text Search API will give you the correct place_id for a closed business. I tried your Text search query with my API key and got 6 different results, none of which were Ye Olde Curiosity Shop. That makes sense, since you probably wouldn't want users to see closed businesses when they're searching for a location.

TL;DR Text search probably doesn't give the correct places_id, but even if it did, it would be ok if that id didn't match the one from an Autocomplete or Places query.